# How do I apply checkable stylesheet properties to multiple QPushButtons with PySide?

Tags: python, pyside, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I'm on an Linux box (Ubuntu 16.04) with Python 3.5 and PySide 1.2.2.

If I have QPushButtons that are not checkable, and I only set the style sheet once, the buttons appear the way that I would like. However, if I make them checkable, Qt wants to play with focused and unfocused style, prioritizing those over what I'd asked for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *

class UI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        outerBox = QGroupBox(self)
        outerBox.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 150)
        outerBox.setObjectName("outerBox")

        brokenCss  = "QPushButton:unchecked {"
        brokenCss += "  background-color:  #ce9a9a;"  # red-ish
        brokenCss += "  border: 1px outset #000000;"
        brokenCss += "  border-radius: 6px;"
        brokenCss += "}"
        brokenCss += "QPushButton:checked {"
        brokenCss += "  background-color:  #12f785;"  # green-ish
        brokenCss += "  border: 1px inset  #000000;"
        brokenCss += "  border-radius: 6px;"
        brokenCss += "}"

        broken = []
        for i in range(2):
            broken.append(QPushButton(outerBox))
            broken[i].setObjectName("broken{0}".format(i))
            broken[i].setGeometry(15, (35 * (i + 1)), 100, 20)
            broken[i].setText("Broken CSS {0}".format(i))
            broken[i].setCheckable(True)
            broken[i].setChecked(False)
            broken[i].setStyleSheet(brokenCss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UI()
    ui.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was hoping the above would produce two red-ish buttons at startup, which would then turn green-ish and remain green-ish once they have been pressed once (and flip back to red-ish when clicked again).  Instead I see:

[image: A focused button and an unfocused button]

Once they are both clicked they each turn green, though most recently clicked is slightly darker, indicating focus, I guess. But toggling them back to off gives me the image above again, instead of two red buttons.

I have tried adding CSS "stanzas" for `:default`, `:flat` and several other pseudo-states, all to no avail.

Comment: Although there was a typo in the above version (I had a " = " where I should have a " += ") that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the documentation does not match reality. `unchecked` and `checked` were the documented way to do what I wanted, but after experimenting with `off` and `on` which were equally ineffective, I tried `closed` and `open`, which, as I understand from the documentation, is only supposed to apply to QPushButtons with menus attached. Nonetheless, that worked. (It doesn't seem to be doing the `outset` and `inset` but it's getting the colors right.)

I also switched to PyQt5 to see if there would be a change, but it behaved the same as PySide.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *

class UI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        outerBox = QGroupBox(self)
        outerBox.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 150)
        outerBox.setObjectName("outerBox")

        brokenCss  = "QPushButton:closed {"
        brokenCss += "  background-color:  #ce9a9a;"  # red-ish
        brokenCss += "  border: 1px outset #000000;"
        brokenCss += "  border-radius: 6px;"
        brokenCss += "}"
        brokenCss += "QPushButton:open {"
        brokenCss += "  background-color:  #12f785;"  # green-ish
        brokenCss += "  border: 1px inset  #000000;"
        brokenCss += "  border-radius: 6px;"
        brokenCss += "}"

        broken = []
        for i in range(2):
            broken.append(QPushButton(outerBox))
            broken[i].setObjectName("broken{0}".format(i))
            broken[i].setGeometry(15, (35 * (i + 1)), 100, 20)
            broken[i].setText("Broken CSS {0}".format(i))
            broken[i].setCheckable(True)
            broken[i].setChecked(False)
            broken[i].setStyleSheet(brokenCss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UI()
    ui.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```